# Facebook likes provide promotional code

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, promotion-code

I'm looking into application (or something like that) that will help me in this case:

I want to provide customer a promotional code (discout -20%) when he click "LIKE" on our facebook page. Still, don't know how to do that. Googled a lot, but couldn't find clear answear. Where should I start looking? What to google; where to stop googling and start reading?

Sorry if this doesn't fit in this web content; but couldn't find that i thought that this is associated with programming.

Comment: That is not allowed by Facebook Platform Policy

Comment: Oh, sorry to hear that then :/ so bad.